# Windows IoT on Raspberry Pi: how to eliminate huge variations in reading pins values? (C#)

Tags: gpio, sensor, windows-iot

I have been porting the library for HX711 (Weighting sensor module amplifier) for Arduino to C# for Raspberry Pi Windows 10 Core. [Source here on GitHub Arduino library](https://github.com/bogde/HX711)

It does work, I am even using basically the very same calibration_factor I was using on Arduino, so it seems the code side of things is working as expected.

BUT, and that is the reason for my questions, I see some (seemingly random) readings that are way out of line. Meaning, with no weight on the scale, I normally read a value 1/2 gram around 0 (+ or -), but sometimes, I read values of ~500, or even around 1 million something! (Then it get immediately back to expected values)

I guess I could code around this to eliminate values + or - 10% around a sample of readings, but I wonder if there would not be some electronic way to regulate pins readings, instead of coding around.

I was having variations on the Arduino, but never of such magnitude.

Comment: I did not investigate how the sensor works but beware if it does not hold the signal low, and you have not used/configured a pull-down, the input value will float as if disconnected.  This may be the case if the problem only occurs with the scale unloaded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not a specialist, so it may take me a little time to fully understand and use this idea, but I will do my best to try.

Comment: I'm probably wrong, looking at [that thing here](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/load-cell-amplifier-hx711-breakout-hookup-guide).  It would only make sense if when unloaded there is something that literally disconnects the input from anything including ground.  By "floating" I mean a [high-Z state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_impedance); this is what a bare pin does.

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you place a weight on? Do you get random high values?

Comment: @goldilocks - Thanks for your interest and your answers. It does  not happen only when the scale is unloaded, and from the way pins are initialized, I doubt one would be "bare".

Comment: @ppumkin - Yes, it does happen with a weight on.

Comment: Could you post the complete iot version of the codw here. I have tried to convert to Windows iot, but failed so far

Answer (score 3):

As I did not find another way, I coded around the difficulty. It's not perfect, but is better than nothing.

Instead of simply returning an average of readings, I eliminate the 2 higher, as it seems the problem is always with big values:

```
public float read_average(int times = 10)
    {
        float[] readings = new float[times];
        float sum = 0;
        for (byte i = 0; i < times; i++)
        {
            readings[i] = read();               
        }
        Array.Sort(readings);
        for (byte y = 0; y < (times - 2); y++) // eliminate the 2 larger values.....
        {
            sum += readings[y];
        }
        return sum / (times - 2);
    }
```

`Array.Sort` makes this easy.
If anyone has a better way, I am listening...

**EDIT**

Based on your answers, here is the revised method, where I first take out extreme values, then filter based on average + and - a percentage:

```
    public float read_average(int times = 10)
            {

                float[] readings = new float[times];
                float sum = 0;
                float goodSum = 0;
                for (short i = 0; i < times; i++)
                {
                    readings[i] = read();               
                }
                Array.Sort(readings);
                for (short y = 1; y < (times - 2); y++) // eliminate extreme values.....
                {
                    sum += readings[y];
                }
                float avread = sum / (times - 3);
                float avreadPlustenpercent = avread * (float)(1.0 + SPREAD);
                float avreadMinustenpercent = avread * (float)(1.0 - SPREAD);

                List<float> goodReads = new List<float>();
                for(short w = 0; w < (times -2); w++)
                {
                    if (readings[w] < avreadPlustenpercent && readings[w] > avreadMinustenpercent)
                    {
                        goodReads.Add(readings[w]);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var item in goodReads)
                {
                    goodSum += item;
                }
                if (goodReads.Count > 0)
                {
                    return goodSum / goodReads.Count;
                }
                else
                    return 0;


            }
```

Comment: For now, maybe checking if the value if above a threshhold, dont know wha the max is on this? But set a upper limit maybe and discard any reading that is way above the limit. The issue may be a IoT Driver problem or an OS latency issue, but maybe a pull down is required on the pin to help solve this. Did you set your code to initialise the pin with pull down? On the Pi you can set if you want the PIN pulled up or down after init, unlike Arduino where you have to pull it down manually with a resistor

Comment: Also from a C# sematics point of view, you should not use `byte` as a counter as it is really reserved for byte arrays. I know its 255 and only takes up 8 bits in memory, but it is more readable to use `short` or `int` - Just from a professional point of view - as bytes cause conversion issues later if you tend to overuse them, and really the extra bits wont cause any serious problems with memory, leaving your code to be more future proof. One problem I see now if if somebody set times to 300, your loop will cause an exception when hitting 255+1, or overflow and never end.

Comment: Did you have a look at this source code? https://github.com/ggurov/hx711 - It is Raspberry Pi specific. The Pi may contain some specific GPIO settings that Arduino does not require. It seems like the problem is caused by OS not being realtime like Arduino. So you have to put in software safeguards against crazy values.

Comment: @ppumkin - Thanks for your help. I had been looking at the source code you linked to, and used his idea in my revamped read-average method. I filter twice, and its much better now. Maybe not perfect, but usable for the calculations I need to make based on those readings.